# GTM - CSS Element

Tags: css, google-tag-manager

I'm wanting to create a variable to grab the username from a landing page (assuming it's possible).  In my attached examples, I'd like to grab the text "Landing_page_test".

I'm just learning CSS so I'm not able to single out just that text.

Any thoughts/suggestions would be much appreciated! enter image description here

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwz0c.jpg)

[Elements Pane of Landing Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KzbR.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to put that text into a custom Javascript variable in GTM?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was hoping to do.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.querySelector returns an element, not the text. Add `.innerText`

Try it out on this page: `document.querySelector("a.question-hyperlink").innerText` to get the name of the question.

But you probably don't want to do it as custom html tag. You probably want to do it on click. in that case, you have {{Clicked Element}} variable in GTM, of which you can also get .innerText, or get its .parentElement and further navigate DOM from the clicked element as you wish and get whatever you need.

Comment: The Text (username) would need to be captured on page load, not by click.  Would that change anything or would I need a different query?

Comment: I was able to get the username text with your innerText suggestion - document.querySelector (".wel-name").innerText.   In GTM, I used ".wel-name.innerText" & it worked.  Appreciate the help but let me know if I'm missing anything else

Comment: timing generally may be important (pageload versus click) if the elements are added to the page later on by JS, but it's not your case, so you're good.

Comment: Awesome - thanks again, appreciate the quick response!  One other question I've been running into as well and not sure if there is a query to get around it.  I'm trying to get at separate text blocks but they are using the same Class i.e. Address & Date.  Typically I could use 0, 1, 2, etc when working within a DataLayer to choose the 1st or 2nd option but not sure how to do that within CSS

Comment: Can you show the html of the text blocks?

Comment: Yes, I posted a screenshot. Thanks

Comment: you can look into nth-child or nth-of-type selectors, but at this point I would just use a piece of javascript in a variable to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the html of the Location & Date/Time text blocks

[Text Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quGCr.jpg)

Comment: In text format. So that I could actually test it.